# Is it correct to say, "There is no enough room in the lift (or the elevator)"?

Tags: word-choice

Let's say I am in the elevator and it is full, when someone is trying to get into the lift.

Is it correct to say, "There is no enough room in the lift."?

Comment: instead of room you can use `space`.

Comment: _no enough_ is not correct. You can either say there is _no room_, or you can say there is _not enough room_. That is grammatically correct. Depending on the situation, it may or may not be socially acceptable.

Comment: @oerkelens Make it an answer.

Comment: @Srikanth I'd normally say "I'm sorry. It's already full." or "Sorry, it's full!." (compromising politeness with the need to be quick) in such a situation.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> *no enough room* in the elevator

is not accepted especially by native speakers. Though I have seen such constructions, here in India and probably in Asia. Examples are [here](http://www.nyasatimes.com/2014/08/17/tigers-beat-kb-to-reach-semis-of-standard-bank-cup/), [here](http://www.deccanchronicle.com/141012/nation-current-affairs/article/threat-coast-erosion-east-godavari-district) and [here](http://www.asiantribune.com/node/85724).

So, you better may say...

> there's not enough room or there's no room.

There is an idiom I remember *['not enough room to swing a cat or no room to swing a cat'](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/no-not-enough-room-to-swing-a-cat).*

However, it's good to note (as *oerkelens* defines) that it may or **may not** be socially acceptable.

To stay clear, I'd tell someone -

> I think, it'll be *overloaded*.

---

The answer is rewritten after having useful comments on the topic.

Comment: You've misunderstood that idiom. It's either 'not enough room to swing a cat', or 'no room to swing a cat'. 'No enough room to swing a cat' is plain wrong.

Comment: The only way that "no enough" would be acceptable is in certain dialects where the "t" gets "swallowed". That is, however, absolutely no standard English! "No' enough 'e says? No' enough room? 's plen'y o' room!"

Comment: @ No enough space on the disk looks absolutely fine @AlanThird

Comment: It may look fine to you, but it's wrong in English.

Comment: @MaulikV please consider changing your answer further.  _"No enough"_ is **not** "fine though rare" in the United States or England.  It sounds painfully awkward.  Google ngrams supports this: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+enough%2C+not+enough&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cno%20enough%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bno%20enough%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNo%20enough%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNo%20Enough%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNO%20enough%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cnot%20enough%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnot%20enough%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNot%20enough%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Adam corrected. But for your reference [here](http://www.deccanchronicle.com/141012/nation-current-affairs/article/threat-coast-erosion-east-godavari-district), [here](http://www.nyasatimes.com/2014/08/17/tigers-beat-kb-to-reach-semis-of-standard-bank-cup/), and [here](http://www.asiantribune.com/node/85724)

Comment: @MaulikV Your first example is almost certainly not written by a native speaker. It's full of mistakes. The other two may be written by native speakers, they're certainly better at English than the first one, but even so, I'm pretty certain that their use of 'no enough' is a typographical error. In your native language do people never make typos? I've changed my downvote after your edit.

Comment: @AlanThird people do make typos but they don't *speak by mistake* I've heard this usage. Maybe again, Indian dialect that at times make natives wonder. :-)

Comment: @MaulikV Fair enough. Regional variations can be so extensive and unexpected. Since starting using this site I've learned a few ways that people speak in Scotland that is non-standard or strange elsewhere. They're always a bit of a surprise. :)

Answer (score 6):

for starters, *no enough* is not correct.

You can either say there is *no room*, or you can say there is *not enough room*: both are  grammatically correct.

Depending on the situation, it may or may not be socially acceptable.

As for the link that MaulikV posted: "no/not enough room to swing a cat" should be parsed as:

> [no]/[not enough] [room to swing a cat]

not as

> [no]/[not] [enough room to swing a cat]

Comment: No enough space on the disk looks absolutely ok

Comment: @MaulikV: I think it warrants its own question, but generally, "no enough" will be seen as wrong, ugly, non-idiomatic, strange, pidgin, or at least a typo by (most?) native speakers. Check the results [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=%22no%20enough%22) returns... mostly about a Chinese movie title. [This](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100829010839AALPvWG) may also be interesting to read.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by it may not be socially acceptable? Also, just to confuse matters, in Scots (or Scot-English, if you prefer) 'no' has the same meaning as English 'not', so it should be possible to find examples of native English speakers saying 'no enough', but that's because they're not speaking English, as such.

Comment: @AlanThird: I can think of situations where a remark like this would be plain rude. This may depend on cultural preferences and customs, and on the specifics of the situation. Telling your obese boss that there is "not enough room in the elevator" may be a bad idea if stepping out and _making_ room could save you your job ;) About the Scots - I did comments along those lines under Maulik's answer :)

Comment: @oerkelens Hah, I missed your comment entirely on Maulik's answer. I see what you mean about social acceptability. :)